# JQuery UI display message alert-like

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jinja2

I have an HTML table and the last column of the table is a button to "Details" that for the moment displays an alert with the content I pass. This works fine but is ugly. I know of JQuery dialog, but I can't seem to pass the message to it. I would like to know if there is a nicer way to display content like alert does.

The code:

```
<tr>
  <td>{{date}}</td>
  <td>{{item_name}}</td>
  <td>{{type}}</td>
  <td>{{points}}</td>
  <td>{{item_options}}</td>
  <td><button onclick="detailer('{{other}}')">Details</button></td>
</tr>

<script>
  function detailer(pii_other){
    alert(pii_other);
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're unable to pass the message but are you able to bring up the jQuery dialog?

Comment: @MarkWade, I could add an id to the button and show a dialog out of it but without passing a content message to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a data-* attribute to your button as below and pass the control to the function:

```
<td><button data-info='some-info' onclick="detailer('{{other}}',this)">Details</button></td>
```

and then in your function retrieve the data property of the particular control as below:

```
<script>
  function detailer(pii_other, ctrl){
    var info = $(ctrl).data('info');
    alert(pii_other + ' ' + info);
}
</script>
```

**EDIT -** Ok let's go your way

```
<td><button data-info='some-info' id="opener">Details</button></td>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

You will initialize your dialog as below:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });

    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
      $("#dialog p").text($(this).data("info")); //Here your dialog will get info from the button you clicked everytime!!
    });
});
```

Comment: remove the alert then from the function!! You wanted to pass some message to the alert from control and that's how you can easily achieve it.. :)

Comment: I think you are confused here, I'm trying to display a message but alert is ugly. I want something like dialog() which can't receive the data to show like alert does.

Comment: Edited the answer!! check it and let me know.. :)

Comment: This looks very good, but I'm confused about the button. Could you update the button part please ? So I can test it.

Comment: There you go!! Added button part too @PepperoniPizza.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with jinja but you could just put this in the jquery dialog markup

`<div id="dialogContent"></div>`

give the button an id

`<button id="myButton"></button>`

and have an event like

`$("#myButton").click(function() {
    $("#dialogContent").html([CONTENT GOES HERE]);
});`

then there's no need for the onclick currently in your button.